# Is there a difference between "login" and "log in"?

Tags: login, grammar

I always thought *login* is the noun and *log in* is the verb. For example, "you need to log in using the modal login window". Is this really the case or can they be used interchangeably? Does *logout* and *log out* follow the same rule?

Comment: Pretty sure Donald Norman wrote an essay on this topic quite some time ago. Sadly, google is not my friend with these keywords.

Comment: fwiw, we're using "sign in" here.

Comment: *login* is [not a verb](http://notaverb.com/login). *log in* is a *verb phrase*. [more info on english.se](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23178/login-or-log-in)

Comment: When I clicked to give you a thumbs up it said: "Please login or register to vote for this post."

Comment: Somewhat related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20595/sign-up-vs-create-an-account/ (not saying it's a duplicate)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"Login" is a noun or adjective.  "Log in" is a verb.

Go to the login page. - adjective

Go to your login. - noun

Log in to twitter. - verb

Comment: Same rule for "logout" and "log out," although logout is rarely used as an adjective ("logout page?") and has no meaning as a noun as far as I can figure.  But the verb is "log out."

Comment: This never occurred to me, thanks for taking the time to answer. Makes sense.

Comment: Not sure login can serve as an adjective, so as lion is not an adjective in "Go to the lion cage".

Comment: We were leaving a hotel one time and my 7 yeard old said "Are we logging out now?".  So, she was using it as a VERB :)