# Is it more clear to use "Login | Sign up" rather than "Sign in | Sign up"

Tags: wording

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Sign Up” vs “Create an Account”](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20595/sign-up-vs-create-an-account)

"Login | Sign up" seems to have more contrast than "Sign in | Sign up" especially for people who don't good at english.

So it is more clear to use  "Login | Sign up" than "Sign in | Sign up"

Comment: Obligatory note: http://loginisnotaverb.com

Comment: Related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20595/sign-up-vs-create-an-account/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Swain0 and if you want an alternative - which seems to be easier and faster to understand, specially for ESL people(my case) - you can use Login | Register

Comment: Also "password reminder" instead of "forgotten password" as less negative from user's perspective.

Answer (score 3):

My vote for "Login | Sign up" because users will know the differences. In first glance, *"oh this is for "Login" and this is for Signup"*.

Also keep both button alongside. or we can give some color variations, so that it will give more visual emphasis.

---

OPTION2:

If you use "Sign in | Sign up", users will have some confusion when he looks at it for the first time.

"Sign" is given more emphasis than "in" & "out" which are in the second position.

if you take this terminology, you need to consider some points:

- Button position
- Button color
- Button / Link
- Various Visual emphasis

Also you can find more help from this post:
http://www.leemunroe.com/login-vs-signin/

Comment: Also you can use "Sign In | Create new account". It looks more usable.

Answer (score 1):

Sign In / Sign Up will increase users' cognitive load because they'll have to concentrate on what it means. Login / Sign up is familiar and they can access without thinking about it.