# drop down menu login or login page for easier user experience

Tags: login, homepage

I've been observing a couple of websites, and leading brands using drop down menu,
and some using just a login page.

I know Google uses a login page for you to log in to your inbox. When you visit [gmail](http://gmail.com) there's an initial page with slideshow, then when you click login, it takes you to another page for you to login.

For [yahoo](http://yahoomail.com) it just takes you to the home page with the login section on the homepage, same with facebook. 
Twitter also, they use a drop down menu for login, which is on the homepage.

This reduces the amount of mouse clicks and movement of the mouse the user has to engage in when they want to login, as a good law of simplicity in design.

I'm build a fully functioning desktop based site, that is mobile responsive, there's a login page, a login section, but the idea is: would it be necessary to have a drop down menu, for easier navigation so they won't have to visit the login page initially.

I'm confused on which model to follow.

Should i make my login page on another page, or keep it on the homepage which could be either a section on the home page, or a drop down menu?

Comment: Also a similar question is this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29492/what-is-the-name-of-the-button-that-lead-to-a-login-and-register-page-one-page

Comment: I would recommend reopening this since this question about the debate of using login dropdowns vs login pages. It is kind of similar to the example quoted but not exactly similar

Comment: @MervinJohnsingh: None of the sites mentioned in the question use log in dropdowns (whatever they are - that isn't explained) they're just on-page log in form fields, and the actual question text of this post is *"Should i make my login page on another page, or keep it on the homepage"* which is a duplicate.